# How do I set the severity of a stackdriver log entry in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

So I am doing some simple logging to GCP stackdriver using v1 of the python google cloud logging library (see below).  I'm not clear on how to set the "severity" level for the log entry. The severity currently shows up in Stackdriver as "default" when I log as below.  How do I set the severity?  It isn't clear to me from the documentation.

```
import google.cloud.logging as glog1

def do_v1_log():
    # Instantiates a client
    logging_client = glog1.Client()

    # The name of the log to write to
    log_name = 'gregs-log'
    # Selects the log to write to
    logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)
    
    # Writes the log entry
    logger.log_struct({'name': 'Greg', 'phone': '619-555-1809'})


# Main bootstrapping routine
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # main()
    do_v1_log()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the severity in the log entry :

[LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry)

[Python Client for Stackdriver Logging¶](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/index.html)

> severity   enum (LogSeverity)
>
> Optional. The severity of the log entry. The default value is
> LogSeverity.DEFAULT.

```
from google.cloud import logging_v2
client = logging_v2.LoggingServiceV2Client()

resource = {
    "type": "global",
    "labels": {
        "project_id": "[PROJECT_ID]"
    }
}


e = logging_v2.types.LogEntry(
    log_name="projects/[PROJECT_ID]/logs/test-logging", # optional
    resource=resource, # optional
    text_payload="this is a log statement",
    severity="WARNING")

entries = [e]
response = client.write_log_entries(entries)
```

Another example of [Writing log entries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/tasks/creating-logs)

```
def write_entry(logger_name):
    """Writes log entries to the given logger."""
    logging_client = logging.Client()

    # This log can be found in the Cloud Logging console under 'Custom Logs'.
    logger = logging_client.logger(logger_name)

    # Make a simple text log
    logger.log_text('Hello, world!')

    # Simple text log with severity.
    logger.log_text('Goodbye, world!', severity='ERROR')

    # Struct log. The struct can be any JSON-serializable dictionary.
    logger.log_struct({
        'name': 'King Arthur',
        'quest': 'Find the Holy Grail',
        'favorite_color': 'Blue'
    })

    print('Wrote logs to {}.'.format(logger.name))
```

Comment: So, it looks like to set the severity in the "log_struct" call, "severity" is a parameter that can be sent.

Comment: I am not clear on how to specify the content of a v2 payload using json.  There is a "json_payload" parameter that can be used instead of "text_payload", but I'm not clear on the type/format.  If I pass in a "dictionary", I get an error, if I pass in a string, I get an error. So doing something like:  json_payload = {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"} gives me:  ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "key1" field.